# Cache value from xml that is loaded trough php

Tags: php, xml, caching

I currently load some values from a xml file and print that trough php.

But this file itself is only updated once a day, so the values will only be updated once a day.

Is there a way to cache the values for a day? 
So that it does not need to check every time the page is loaded, the values from the xml, but it loaded the cached strings.

My current code:

```
  <?php $xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.linktoxml.com");
if (!$xml) {
     echo "";
} else {
echo "<span itemprop='aggregateRating' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/AggregateRating'>Review value<strong>
<span itemprop='ratingValue'>";
 foreach($xml->children() as $average)
{
echo $average->total_score;
}
echo "</span>/<span itemprop='bestRating'>10</span></strong>";
echo "<span class='review-link total' itemprop='ratingCount'>";
foreach($xml->children() as $total_review)
{
    echo $total_review->total_reviews;
}
echo "</span></span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes there is a way. Probably a few of them. But this question is much too broad.